# OOP, adding a returned variable from a method in to parenthesis of another method

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have the following script. I have returned variable called minima from a method (i.e max_Impact). I want to use that variable along with other variables including self in another method (i.e netloss). However, when I do, I get an error called "name self is not defined". If I were to remove self (i.e def netloss(self,lim1 = 0, lim2 = minima): ). Then I get an error called "name minima is not defined". Any ideas about how to solve this issue.
Note, I am referring to the last 2 methods, I have added some of the other function for just reference.

```
#Imports
import numpy as np 
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import integrate

# Function just for reference
def polynomial_eq2(x):
p4eq = lambda x: clf4.intercept_[0] + clf4.coef_[0][1] * x + clf4.coef_[0][2]*np.power(x,2) + clf4.coef_[0][3]*np.power(x,3) + clf4.coef_[0][4]*np.power(x,4)
return integrate.quad(p4eq,lim1,lim2)

class ImpRec():
def __init__(self,X,Y):
    self.X = X
    self.Y = Y
    self.minima_index = argrelextrema(self.Y,np.less)
    self.maxima_index = argrelextrema(self.Y,np.greater)
    self.approx_converge_pt = []
    self.approx_converge_idx = []

 #Calculates local minima
def max_impact(self):
    self.minima = self.Y[self.minima_index] #self.minima
    return (self.minima)

..... #bunch of other methods

 def netloss(self,lim1 = 0, lim2 = self.minima):
    sol_netloss = integrate.quad(polynomial_eq2,self.lim1,self.lim2)
    return (sol_netloss)
```

Comment: You have to define self.minima in initialization function and compute its value there and remove function max_impact. Since self.minima is computed in another function you cannot use its value as argument to another function

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
def netloss(self,lim1 = 0):
    lim2 = self.minima
    sol_netloss = integrate.quad(polynomial_eq2,self.lim1,lim2)
    return (sol_netloss)
```

and you have to call `max_impact` before call the `netloss`.otherwise self.minima is not available